# Clicking leave closed shows the reopen pop-up

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

This is rather difficult to describe with fancy pictures with red circles but it's easily reproducible.

Whenever I click Leave Closed in the re-open queue on MSO the "nominate this question for re-opening" pop-up appears. I normally press escape out of shock and a leave closed vote is recorded.

This is the latest review it's happened to me on: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15029

You can also test it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15043, I clicked reopen this time and a leave closed vote was recorded but I also got a red popup stating that an error had occurred.

This is also occurring when the Edit & Reopen button is clicked, the edit box opens for a second before being overridden by the popup.

Comment: Whoah! That is indeed shocking. Reproduced the error with that exact same queue entry.

Comment: I just thought I'd misclicked earlier, glad to know I'm not going crazy

Comment: It took this happening a couple of times before I believed that I wasn't going crazy an mis-clicking everywhere @rory :-).

Comment: This is still ongoing today

Comment: Repro'ed on Mac Chrome.

Comment: I just got it on SO using firefox. Tried only with Cancel.

Comment: And on SO with Safari just now - which button do I press to leave closed?

Comment: This happens to me every time. I click Cancel if I want to leave it closed but I don't know what that does!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186099/205264

Comment: Just posted this on Mathematics Meta: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10082/43351).

Comment: Just posted this on Workplace.SE: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1908/when-reviewing-re-open-candidates-the-message-prompt-is-wrong

Comment: Also on AskDifferent on reopening it gave me the dialog twice

Comment: Clicking "Cancel" votes to reopen as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oops, this was caused by a javascript copy-paste gone awry. It's fixed now – sorry about that.

Comment: a worry is that this was reported 10 days ago but needed a bounty to get a response from a developer

Comment: @Mark - It wasn't the bounty that did it.

Answer (score 8):

Experienced this on a non-mSO site today, so not fixed. The extra popup is shocking because it asks the direct OPPOSITE of what I pressed.

I press "Leave closed", the popup asks "Nominate this question for re-opening?". Please, pretty please don't shock us like that.

Thus, I suggest either getting rid of this confirmation popup, or re-wording it to avoid astonishment ("Man, WTF! Have I pressed the wrong button?").

This is a UX misfeature on par with the infamous: "Cancel this operation? Cancel (to proceed) OK (to cancel)".

Answer (score 8):

Question and other answer cover it but barely (due to lack of images), here's the prerequisite hand drawn circle from SO:[image]

Comment: And you actually get to vote on reopening(+1) if you do that :S

Answer (score 6):

I started getting this today systematically on all Reopen Keep Closed votes. Reproduces on Chrome on both OSX and Win7.

In addition, clicking Reopen will prompt the "Nominate this question for reopening?" dialog twice. When clicking ok on the second dialog, there's the error message "You have already voted" (or something similar), the Reopen vote itself is recorded properly.

Answer (score 3):

I just clicked "Edit and Reopen" and the item went away having apparently recorded my Reopen. I used my history to go find the question and edit it.

At this rate, I don't think reiew results are going to be very meaningful. We are casting votes we didn't mean to cast... maybe,

Answer (score 2):

This is happening on ServerFault today, clearly related to the new close vote reasons.

[Review bug: I pick "leave closed" and it pops up "Nominate for re-opening?"](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5597/review-bug-i-pick-leave-closed-and-it-pops-up-nominate-for-re-opening)