# Nominate for Reopening Shows Duplicate Message Boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing a question in the *Reopen Votes* queue, there are two main options: **Leave Closed** and **Nominate for Reopening**.

If I click **Nominate for Reopening**, a message box appears asking me if I am sure I want to *vote to reopen*:

- If I click **cancel**, a second message box appears with the same question.

  - If I click **cancel** on the second message box is dismissed the message box, but nothing else happens.
- If I click **okay**, a second message box appears with the same question.

  - If I click **okay** on the second message box is dismissed the message box, and a vote to reopen is cast.
  - If I click **cancel** on the second message box is dismissed the message box, and a vote to reopen is cast.

I haven't yet exhausted all possible ways of interacting with these message boxes, but there is definitely at least one bug here.

---

A similar, and possibly related issue exists with the **Leave Closed** option. If I click **Leave Closed**, a message box appears asking me if I am sure I want to *vote to reopen*:

- If I click **cancel**, the message box is dismissed, and my vote to leave closed is cast.
- If I instead click **okay** the message box is dismissed, and my vote to leave closed is cast, but I occasionally see the error, "*An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again.*"

Using Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: @NiallC. I've shifted the focus of my question to the duplicate confirmation bug, so it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough; I'm going to leave the comment there (I can't edit it at this point unfortunately) as a link to the related question.  With as much activity as meta is seeing right now, I think it would have been closed already if it was going to be closed.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186188/130264

Comment: @laalto Indeed it is. If *Emmett♦*, *Oded♦*, you, or anyone for that matter wants to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186188/365152) by [Emmett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144066/emmett):

> Oops, this was caused by a javascript copy-paste gone awry. It's fixed now – sorry about that.