# misbehaviour of "Leave closed" button in "Reopen" reviews

Tags: bug, status-completed

Story:

While browsing through Reopen reviews, I've clicked at "Leave Closed" button and I was presented with a modal dialog asking me to "Nominate the post for reopening / OK / Cancel". I've pressed "Cancel" and the case was resolved as I wanted: LeftClosed. I do not know what happens if I'd pressed "OK". I've not checked that in case it would interpret it as "Reopen" vote.

Bug/suggestion:

As far as I remember, the popup was related to "Reopen" button, not to "Leave closed" one. For "Leave closed" it makes a little sense. I think that 'back then' there was no popup dialog at all when voting for leave-closed, so I think that this dialog should be simply skipped for that button.

Repeatability:

100% over two 'leave closed' votes today.

Comment: Not just for @quetzalcoatl also occurred for me

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184603/209087

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is exactly the same issue. I've not found it via search. Should I delete or mark as duplicate?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It looks like Oded beat you to it... I think the consensus is not to delete duplicates, for searchability reasons

Comment: @user000001: I don't like deleting and this is what I was thinking about, but thought that it'll be better to ask. Thanks for the note!