# Bug: Audit failure message in re-open queue - after choosing correct action

Tags: bug, review-audits

This [review in the reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2389007) produced the stop-look-and-listen suggestion *you should Close such questions*  Which I did by clicking the leave-closed button ... as history confirms

Might be related to [Clicking leave closed shows the reopen pop-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184603/159794)

Comment: The review shows "audit passed"

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, I know - but it showed the failure dialog before listing the passed in the history