# Clicking reopen shows the reopen pop-up twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

This is related to this question: [Clicking leave closed shows the reopen pop-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184603/205264)

There's more to it: when you click to reopen, the pop-up "do you want to reopen?" shows twice. To be sure, I clicked "OK" twice. The second time, I got a message: "you have already voted to reopen this question".

Comment: I've got this a few times, it's irritating.

Comment: Stop re-opening. Problem solved.