# How to get to the "leave closed/reopen/etc" dialogue window of a question in the reopen queue?

Tags: support, review, dupehammer

I suspect this has been explained somewhere, but I could not find it. Apparently I have never needed to do the following before, so I lost my way.

Anyway, here's what happened at Math.SE today.

1. Another user had used their dupehammer to close a question as a dupe.
2. There was disagreement, and the question started collecting reopen votes.
3. The hammerer pinged me for support.
4. I came to the scene. I decided to agree with the decision to close. So I wanted to vote "leave closed". Only I couldn't find a way to enter the voting dialogue...
5. I decided to check out the reopen queue. To my amazement this question was not listed there.
6. So, not being entirely helpless, I check out close/reopen menu from Tools. Sure enough, I see the question there. I click it, and I still don't see the dialogue. Only a suggestion to vote to reopen.
7. I begin to search. The best match is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184603/169003).
8. Hmm. So may be I get that dialogue window by clicking the "reopen" button?
9. Nope, my clicking that button caused the question to be reopened on the spot. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2951504/revisions).
10. What have I done?! To repair the damage I nominate the question to be closed.
11. The question is insta-closed. Ahh! I, too, have the required dupehammer privilege.

> Is the rule that a voter with a dupehammer privilege can never vote to "leave closed"? Where is this explained?

Comment: Do you know how much time there was between the first reopen vote and you looking in the queue? I've noticed it sometimes takes a while before questions show up there...

Comment: The ping for me to help came 10 hours ago. It is safe to assume that some reopen votes were there at that time. My misadventure took place 44 minutes ago.

Comment: Is it possible that you cast some sort of vote beforehand on the question? The system, based on certain factors, prevents users who are "involved" in certain questions from reviewing them in the review queue. Such tasks aren't shown to such users if the user goes to the review queue, and if the user has a direct link to the task, it will show "this item is not reviewable". Though I don't see a vote from you that would cause the system to think you're "involved". Out of curiosity, did you upvote or downvote it?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog I have not voted on that question at all. Nor did I get the "this item is not reviewable" message.

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174789/169003), but from the side of users wanting to vote "leave open".

Comment: 10&11 --- The question is tagged abstract-algebra, you have gold badges for [that, finite-fields and group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen?tab=badges), click on one and see:: "Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the X's tag. These users can **single-handedly mark** ***X*** **questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed**. ". You also have 9 silver badges which someday may become gold after you receive a notification (if it arrives).

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I know that much about dupehammers. The problem was that I saw a question marked with 3 votes to reopen, but without a way of entering my vote to "leave closed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You couldn't see the review task because [it was already dismissed with an outcome of Leave Closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1083533).

I was able to find the review task by clicking on the third user to vote to reopen and going to their review actions. The other two reopen voters had voted externally, not through the queue.

As the review item has already been dismissed from the review queue, all users won't see it in the queue anymore unless the existing reopen votes expire and it gets voted for reopening afresh.

By the way, "Leave Closed" is not a *vote*, but rather a *review*, and all it implies is that "I don't think this question should be reopened, this task should be removed from the queue." I don't believe that as a gold badge user, your review would be binding; I don't think SE's set it up that way despite the question being closed as a dupe and moderators getting binding reviews. You couldn't make a review since the task has already been dismissed.

Also, it looks in the edit history like you intentionally reopened and re-closed to clear the reopen votes on the question. Be prepared to do some explaining.

Comment: Ahh! Ok. The review task had been completed. Under the question it still said that there were 3 votes to reopen, which is why I thought the matter is still under consideration. Apparently those votes had not yet aged away or something.

Comment: Accepting your explanation. Somehow, during 7 years on the site and 3½ years with diamond powers, I had managed not to learn these details of the workings of the review queues :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen FYI if you look at the post's timeline, it will show you all the dismissed review tasks for it.

Comment: Thanks. I was used to checking out the timelines. Last summer I gave up my diamond powers. Meaning, among other things, that the familiar route to see the timeline is no longer available to me. I do know that there is another way for privileged users to see it. I just failed to diagnose the situation because the post was still marked with 3 votes to reopen. I was not aware of that being possible after the review task had already closed :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Any user can manually navigate to `/posts/[post ID]/timeline` to see the timeline.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog: Although, of course, for normal users this only shows *completed* reviews, leaving out the pending reviews mods can also see.

Comment: @NathanTuggy In this case, the review was already completed before the author wanted to make one.